# How to open text file in file explorer in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

Is it possible to open a text file in file explorer (DDMS) and see its content?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try to copy the file to your computer by clicking the icon on the right hand side of the Device monitor which looks like a floppy disk and then save it from there.

[image]

Else you can try other third party Android File explorers.

I personally use the first option which works well for me and never tried other explorers so I do not know a good one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. You need to first copy that file to your computer, where then you will have no problem with opening it.

Comment: Hey!
How can i copy it?
Right from file explorer?